# Label ploting always x bar ahead from current bar

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot the resistance and support level away from the current bar always.

In the following code I have to find "resistance_support_label_position" based on todays closing, tomorrow opening, holidays.Beside these its not working as expected on some intervals.I just want my label to be 20th candle away from current candle every time

```
lbl1 := label.new (time, close,xloc=xloc.bar_time,style=label.style_none,textalign=text.align_center)
label.set_y(lbl1,level1)
label.set_x(lbl1, resistance_support_label_position)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you use `xloc=xloc.bar_index` (which is the default value).

Then you can do,

```
label.set_x(lbl1, bar_index + 20)
```

which would be 20 bars away from the current bar.

If you want to do it by using `xloc=xloc.bar_time`, you can convert your chart's timeframe to minutes, then figure out what the time would be in 20 bars in miliseconds.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

f_bar_offset_in_time(p_offset) => int(time + (f_resInMinutes() * 60000 * p_offset))

if barstate.islast
    label.new(f_bar_offset_in_time(20), high, "20 bar offset", xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

[image]

Comment: Not working as I need to pass time value

Comment: Edited my answer and added another way by passing the time.

Comment: As the session closing time is nearer placement of label not working as we have to calculate from next day opening timing